# How to enable/configure the Hudson plugins loging for debugging purpose

Tags: logging, hudson, hudson-plugins

I'm looking to enable/configure the Hudson plugins logging to show when/what the plugin actions are executed. I'm currently interested in [FTP Uploader Plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/FTP-Publisher+Plugin) but a general config will be more than useful:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set up your own "log recorder" to capture a predefined set of log messages under **Manage Hudson** -> **System log**. However, you need to know the "log path" used by whatever you want to follow. For example, I set up a Subversion log recorder to record log messages marked `hudson.scm.SubversionSCM` to try to track down an issue with our subversion server. For me, figuring out the log path was a big stumbling block because I couldn't find any way to get a list of paths that the various Hudson plugins were using for their own messages.

I think by looking at the [Hudson code layout](http://fisheye.hudson-ci.org/browse/Hudson/trunk/hudson/plugins), you can derive the path under which a given java file will log messages:

The Subversion plugin lives in plugins/subversion/src/main/java/**hudson/scm/SubversionSCM.java** (and there are other java files in the same directory).

The FTP Uploader lives in plugins/ftppublisher/src/main/java/**com/zanox/hudson/plugins/FTPPublisher.java**. So maybe you should make a log recorder with the path `com.zanox.hudson.plugins.FTPPublisher`? (Now I'm just guessing though.)

Be warned, I haven't looked at Hudson logging for a little while, so this may be out of date and there may be an easier way. Also my terminology is probably atrocious -- I couldn't think of a better term than "log path"?!?

Answer (score 3):

To list all present Loggers inside hudson, you can use the script console and the following code:

```
import java.util.logging.*;

LogManager.getLogManager().getLoggerNames().each() {
  print "${it} , ";
}
```